# Purge x objects from Realm

Tags: objective-c, realm

I want to purge my event log by removing the oldest `Event` objects but there doesn't seem to be any straight forward way to do this. I can fetch all the object sorted according to how I want them deleted, but there is no way to limit this - ie I just want the first 100 in the RLMResults.

```
RLMResults <Event *> *events = [[Event allObjects] sortedResultsUsingProperty:@"id" ascending:YES];
```

If I loop through and delete them by index the `events` is updated as we go so this won't work.

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[realm beginWriteTransaction];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < numberToPurge; i++) {
    [realm deleteObject:events[i]];
}
[realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

I can put add them into a seperate array and then use that to delete, this way works but seems a bit clunky, is there a better way?

```
NSMutableArray *purgeEvents = [[NSMutableArray alloc]  initWithCapacity:numberToPurge];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < numberToPurge; i++) {
    [purgeEvents addObject:events[i]];
}

RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[realm beginWriteTransaction];
[realm deleteObjects:events];
[realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. At present, the method you used of method of copying just the objects you wish to delete to an `NSArray` and then passing that back to the parent `RLMRealm` object is the recommended way to delete a subset of objects at the moment. It's mentioned [here](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#limiting-results) in the Realm docs.

If you've got any ideas on how you think this could be handled better, please feel free to submit an issue on [the Realm Cocoa GitHub](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa)!

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the collection in reverse.

```
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[realm beginWriteTransaction];
for (NSInteger i = numberToPurge-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    [realm deleteObject:events[i]];
}
[realm commitWriteTransaction];
```